# Generate breadcrumb from database in asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need to generate breadcrumb for any page based on `pageID`. Below is the sample MS Sql server based data sample `sql script`.

```
CREATE TABLE PageMenu
    ([PageId] int, [PageName] varchar(5), path varchar(100), [PageInheritance] int)
;

INSERT INTO PageMenu
    ([PageId], [PageName], [path], [PageInheritance])
VALUES
    (1, 'Home', '/en/', 0),
    (2, 'About Us', '/en/about-us/', 0),
    (3, 'Our Mission', '/en/about-us/our-mission/', 2),
    (4, 'Our Vision', '/en/about-us/our-vision/', 2),
    (5, 'Media', '/en/media/', 0),
    (6, 'Press Release', '/en/media/press-releases/', 5),
    (7, 'Video Gallery', '/en/media/video-gallery/', 5),
    (8, 'Products', '/en/products/', 0),
    (9, 'Mens', '/en/products/mens/', 8),
    (10, 'Womens', '/en/products/womens/', 8),
    (11, 'Footwear', '/en/products/footwear/', 9),
    (12, 'Footwear', '/en/products/footwear/', 10),
    (13, 'Shoes', '/en/products/mens/footwear/shoes/', 9),
    (14, 'Sandals', '/en/products/mens/footwear/sandals/', 9),
    (15, 'Kids', '/en/products/kids/', 8)
;
```

I want to create a CTE based stored procedure which i want to pass `pageid` and it should return recursively the path of the page in form of breadcrumb

suppose if i pass and `pageid=11` then it should return me following rows in below format

```
pageid_____PageName________Path
1          Home            /en/
8          Products        /en/products/
9          Mens            /en/products/mens/
11         Footwear        /en/products/mens/footwear/
```

Based on the above result set then i can generate breadcrumb as below

`Home > Products > Mens  > Footwear`

Comment: "I tried to set it up on sql fiddle by it fails with an some error." - that's really helpful.....

Comment: Row 8 is inherited from 1 not from 0.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, actually `0` is for root level menu all menus like `Home,Products, About us, Media` have PageInheritance as 0. this is how it is actually in my database.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker look at closer. As you say, menu Products is in root. I don't think so. Is Home your root? Or it is under the root?

Comment: Please add your solution as answer instead of incorporating it in your question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I just did that..

Comment: such a good question, why would somebody give it -ve vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
;WITH RecursiveTable (PageId, PageName,  Path, PageInheritance, Level)
AS(
   --Anchor
    SELECT      tt.PageId,  tt.PageName, tt.Path, tt.PageInheritance,  0 AS Level
    FROM pg_Menu AS tt
    WHERE PageId = 13
    UNION ALL
   --Recursion
    SELECT tt.PageId,  tt.PageName,  tt.Path, tt.PageInheritance, Level + 1
    FROM pg_Menu AS tt
    INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rt ON rt.PageInheritance = tt.PageId
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveTable ORDER BY Level DESC
```

**Result for `PageID = 13`**

```
pageid_____PageName________Path
8          Products        /en/products/
9          Mens            /en/products/mens/
11         Footwear        /en/products/mens/footwear/
13         Shoes           /en/products/mens/footwear/shoes/
```

**Update:** Fiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4ce3/2